# What's the difference between installing docker on Windows 10(Hyper-V enabled) and Linux OS?

Tags: docker, windows-10, containers

When we are going to run our applications only on docker containers, and not on the host os, how does it matter if we're in Windows or Linux OS???

Also, I didn't understand these statements:

'**running linux containers on Windows**' 
 '**running windows containers on Linux**'

Are we not running containers on docker. Why host OS is coming into picture and how important is that host OS? Can someone please throw light on this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Docker is a *container*. A container segregates the host OS into different domains. But it's still the host OS.

Comment: Thanks Jorg!!! But, as far as my understanding, docker itself is not a container. **Docker is an engine** on top of which we run docker containers. My question is about the **docker engine**. When we are gonna run our applications inside docker containers which run on top of docker engine, why the host OS is coming into picture here??? that's my doubt..

Comment: Because docker containers are containers. Containers segregate the host OS into different domains. But it's still the host OS.